# Reading part of lines from a txt

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a txt file with informations about time, temperature and humidity, this is the shape

```
07:54:03.383 -> Humidity:38.00%;Temperature:20.50Â°C;Heat index:19.60Â°C;
07:59:03.415 -> Humidity:37.00%;Temperature:20.90Â°C;Heat index:20.01Â°C;
08:04:03.435 -> Humidity:37.00%;Temperature:20.90Â°C;Heat index:20.01Â°C;
08:09:03.484 -> Humidity:37.00%;Temperature:20.80Â°C;Heat index:19.90Â°C;
```

I would like to extrapolate, for each line, the 4 informations and plot them in a graph.
using open() and fileObject.read() i can plot the txt into VSC Terminal, but i don't know how to:

- read the time and save it in a proper way (it's splitted by ":")
- read the values, for example i could think to read the first 5 characters after "Humidity" word, the first 5 after "Temperature" and so on. For each line
- store them in proper vector and then plot the 3 path in function of the time. I'm using numpy as library.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can tolerate reading your data into a Python string, we can use `re.findall` here:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

inp = """07:54:03.383 -> Humidity:38.00%;Temperature:20.50Â°C;Heat index:19.60Â°C;
07:59:03.415 -> Humidity:37.00%;Temperature:20.90Â°C;Heat index:20.01Â°C;
08:04:03.435 -> Humidity:37.00%;Temperature:20.90Â°C;Heat index:20.01Â°C;
08:09:03.484 -> Humidity:37.00%;Temperature:20.80Â°C;Heat index:19.90Â°C;"""

vals = re.findall(r'^(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d+)?) -> Humidity:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%;Temperature:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)Â°C;Heat index:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)Â°C;', inp, flags=re.M)
print(vals)
```

This prints:

```
[('07:54:03.383', '38.00', '20.50', '19.60'),
 ('07:59:03.415', '37.00', '20.90', '20.01'),
 ('08:04:03.435', '37.00', '20.90', '20.01'),
 ('08:09:03.484', '37.00', '20.80', '19.90')]
```

Comment: Why can't I use "time = vals[:,0]" to extract the first column? The error is speaking about "tuple"

Comment: Please provide a context here.  I can't see your code.

Comment: `vals = re.findall(r'^(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d+)?) -> Humidity:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%;Temperature:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)Â°C;Heat index:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)Â°C;', data, flags=re.M)
#print(vals)

time = vals[1,1]
print(time)`

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: @Andrea You intended: `time = vals[1][1] print(time)`

Comment: Yes. But if I use `time = vals[1][:]` I get the same result as `time = vals[:][1]`. Why?

Comment: If you have a doubt about how to use Python list slices, you should open a new question.